# Finding the Length of an External Tangent

Tags: geometry

[image]Determine the length of $PQ$, which is externally tangent to Circle A and Circle B. Given that the radius of circle A is 18 and the radius of circle B is 8.

I know the answer is supposed to be 24. How does this come about? I know the distance between the centers A and B would be 26.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using your drawing which is not in scale.
It is only the pythagorean theorem:
[image]